# Is there a way to find processes that are "Not responding" using Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, activity-monitor

Activity Monitor can indicate processes that are `Not responding`:

[image: Activity Monitor screenshot]

Is there a way to find these processes using command line? Such as with `ps`, ...

Comment: Have you done some prior research (e.g. a websearch)? If so, what methods did you find?

Comment: Helpful insight, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/688024/how-can-i-determine-if-an-application-is-not-responding)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, no such Terminal utility is included with macOS.

The standard tools such as `ps` interact with BSD-style processes on the POSIX layer. `ps` can tell you the state of the process such as the process being "dead", which means a process whose parent is not aware that it has completed running, or the process state being "uninterruptible waiting", which means a process that has asked the kernel to do something which it is waiting for.

Tools such as `ps` are not aware of whether or not processes are "responding" in the context that you have here. The "Not responding" label shown in Activity Monitor means that the application (not process, but application) is no longer processing events in its main GUI event loop (i.e. a Cocoa run loop).

I don't know of any third party utility that allows you to list the non-responding processes from the command line, so I decided to make one. You can download it from here:

https://github.com/jksoegaard/NonResponding

You can download the ready to use binary, or use Xcode to compile it on your own Mac.

Technical note: The program uses a "deprecated" function in order to obtain the information, we're looking for. That the function is deprecated does not mean that it doesn't work, or that it is as such problematic to use it right now. It means that the function will probably be removed from a future version of macOS. The function was deprecated in macOS 10.9, but so far no release version of macOS has a replacement for the function. The upcoming macOS Monterey (10.12) includes a new framework named MetricKit that has an alternative function for querying information about app responsiveness. When Monterey is released it could be possible to use this function instead (depending on what is included in the actual final release of Monterey).

Comment: Related: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7166263

Comment: It's deprecated, but there's no alternative in macOS 10.11, which is what I was running on the system when I made the program. There's an alternative in macOS 10.12 (Monterey), but it is currently in beta and subject to change.

Comment: jksoegaard, Thanks for the comment/Technical note: +1

Comment: macOS 10.12 was Sierra (2016).  Monterey is macOS 12 (2021).

Comment: I hope everyone knew what I meant… no alternative from macOS 10.9 up to macOS 11, and a possibly alternative coming in macOS 12.

Comment: @jksoegaard Thanks, I highly appreciate your effort, market your answer as accepted. (BTW I also noticed the deprecated warning - I guess it'll be good to update the project for Monterey support once the beta is GA)

Comment: As far as I know the program should still work on Monterey. I think there’s a chance that a replacement is available on Monterey, but it’s definitely not a sure thing - more like 10% chance. There’s absolutely no downside to using the current method on the current OS.

Comment: I've never seen any distinction between an application and a process, except that I think of an application as a sort of bundle that includes scripts and assets as well as the/a binary. But I use the term "Application" as a synonym for either the bundle or the process (but not vice-versa). Could you elaborate on the distinction you make in your answer between application and process, if it's different from my own?

Comment: Sure - in this context it's not the same distinction you make. I guess the fine details in having a distinction between "application" and "process" is not really something ordinary users would need to know about, but if you're a software engineer or similar, you would need to know these as separate concepts. In this context a "process" is a specific "unit of execution" that is named a process by the operating system. This is similar to certain types of threads, etc. Typically you would find that a process can be thought of as a "running program with a specific set of allocated resources".

Comment: A process could potentially consist of multiple threads (i.e. you can think of this as multiple parts of the program being run concurrently or even in parallel) - but that is not really relevant here - just to give a broader picture of things.

Comment: An application on the other hand is (in this context) what a normal user would identify as "the running program". If you launch Microsoft Word, you would think of this application as the "running program". Technically a program can register itself with macOS to become an application. Today programs do this through Application Kit (commonly AppKit), which is a part of what is generally known as Cocoa.

Comment: A running application could be a single process running a single thread. It could also be a single process running multiple threads, or it could multiple processes running single threads or multiple threads. All of these combinations are possible. I.e. for example an application such as a web browser would identify as a single application with the system, and the user would think of it it as a single application, but "behind the scenes" it could actually have one process running per tab and also a coordinator process, etc. etc.

Comment: In this very specific context of this question, a process cannot be "non-responding" as this is not defined for processes. There's no requirement (or any general meaning at all) to a process being "responsive". However, when you register to become an application, you're required to be "responsive" - which basically means that you need to periodically ask the system for events in an event loop. Failing to do so makes the application "non-responding".

Comment: To make matters even more complex when you want to actually program this, the way to get to this information has to go through Carbon. In the "old days", Carbon and Cocoa were the two main APIs to use on Mac OS X. Cocoa was "modern" and Carbon "traditional". Carbon is no longer available for ordinary applications in modern macOS, but remnants of it still exist. One of particular interest here is that it is the Carbon Process Manager that actually keeps the lists of running applications and assigns them so called "process serial numbers", which is similar to what you might known as process IDs.

Comment: All BSD-style processes running on macOS (i.e. almost everything you know as a process) have a process ID - but only applications have a process serial number. It is a bit confusing, as you could then say that it perhaps would have been better named an application serial number, but it made sense when it was introduced. The process serial number is the key we need to lookup in the table of running application to see which ones are currently non-responding.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I've tried to use the NonResponding utility, but I can't get it to compile. The error I get is: main.swift:16:9: error: cannot find 'isNonResponding' in scope if( isNonResponding(app.processIdentifier) )

Comment: @SeverusD I got the same error... using `swiftc main.swift` - any updates?  @jksoegaard??

Comment: This is amazing and did the trick. For those who want to compile it, you can use my fork (follow the compile command in the comments) https://gist.github.com/kkirby/cde9ded430bc632381143014f8300aa2